# Is having infinite amount of a quantity same as having none of it?

Tags: materialism, interpretation, infinite

Ithink that if you have an infinite amount of material, you actually have none of it. I interpret this as you having imaginary material.

Am I correct in making this assessment?

Comment: yes, infinity and zero are not the same (infinity is way more uncomprehendable and profitable than zero!;) But I agree, that "in infinite time"(which we're not at) they must be "very close"! maybe `infinity=0`, maybe `infinity+1=0`, maybe `infinty + 1 planck-time=0` ...;) (who cares? in infinity!?;)

Comment: but for an idea like "having infinite material" you need biiiiiig hands/pockets/reservoirs...../tentacles(?;)

Comment: ..and if you don't need tentacles, why would you assume (looking at the night sky) that "you (right now) don't have infinite material"!??

Comment: Infinity is not a static number its a concept. An operation can approach infinity but not equal infinity because Infinity + 1 = Infinity. Mathematicians agree that zero is a number.

Comment: In between there may be only a wonderful veil...

Answer (score 0):

No. Generally speaking, infinity and zero are not the same, and it is unhelpful to mix them up. What you might argue is that it is impossible to have an infinite amount of material (as far as we know), so if someone believes they have it, they must be imagining it.